# php filter a string so that json_encode does not error out

Tags: php

I'm grabbing a bunch of data from a database and putting it into a PHP array.  I'm then looking to json_encode that array using `$output = json_encode($out)`.

My issue is that from time to time, **something** in the array is not able to be read by `json_encode` and the whole thing fails.  If I use `print_r($out)` to have a look, I can clearly see where it's failing, because the character that is screwing things up always appears as a question mark inside of a black diamond `�`.

First - what are these characters?

Second - Is there a function I can pass the elements through prior to adding them to the array that would strip these out, or replace 'them' with blanks?

Comment: Are you using like this print_r(json_encode($array)); ?

Comment: no, but this will fail, as attempting to `json_encode` the array in the first place will fail, so `print_r`ing it will fail as well....

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this.  Since the data coming FROM the database was stored with the "black diamond" character, I needed to get this out POST grabbing it from the database.

```
$x[4]  = utf8_encode(odbc_result($query, 'B'));
```

By passing the result through `utf8_encode`, the string is encoded into UTF-8 and the illegal character is removed.

Answer (score -1):

Say echo json_encode($out);
This will solve your issue

Comment: That fails, because the array `$out` has an illegal character in it that is causing `json_encode` to error out.

Comment: So what was the header ? Is application/json?

Answer (score -1):

Black diamonds are browser issue. Database uses plain question marks.
It seems you are getting already wrong data from databalse. But that's quite tricky to have incorrect utf with your settings. You need to check everything

1. if your table marked with utf8 charset
2. if your data indeed encoded in utf (not marked but indeed encoded)
3. if your server sending correct charset in Content-type header.

it is also useful to see the page choosing different charsets from your browser menu.

But **first of all you have to wipe any trace of all random actions you tried**, all these various encode, decode and stuff. Just plain and direct output from database. Otherwise you will never get to the problem

Comment: Any ideas how I check what the encoding is coming from a Teradata SQL database?

Comment: You need to check the charset of your response and the data in the database

Comment: actually, when I look at the actual table in the database, the field itself has the � in it as well.

Comment: what is the charset of the table ??